# Understanding this rational expression without solving

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My textbook asks to explain in five words or less, what this rational expression does to each number of x.

$(1/x+1/x^2+1/x^3) \div (1/x^4+1/x^5+1/x^6) $

Im not sure how to go about understanding what the rational expression does to each number of x without performing all the operations.

The answer is "it cubes x"

Comment: Given $A,B \neq 0$ then $A \div B = C \iff BC = A.$  Try multiplying the divisor by $x^3$, and see if the product is the dividend.

Comment: If you do not set the parentheses properly, it does not cube $x$.

Comment: Is it $\frac 1x + \frac 1{x^2} + (\frac 1{x^3}\div \frac 1{x^4}) + \frac 1{x^5} + \frac 1{x^6}$ or is it $(\frac 1x + \frac 1{x^2} + \frac 1{x^3})\div ( \frac 1{x^4}+ \frac 1{x^5} + \frac 1{x^6})$? It makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: "Understanding this rational expression *without solving*" (emphasize mine). Why do you think you aren't supposed to solve?  You are suppose to *explain* it in five words or less.  But that doesn't mean you can't spend hundreds of hours and thousands of pages of notes trying to figure it out first.  It's just that *after* you figure it out, you have to explain the answer in five words.

Comment: So *do* do all the steps... take as long as you like and waste as much paper as you need.  In the end you will find out the whole thing equals $x^3$.  Then pick up all your papers and toss them in the trash.  Turn on the zoom camera and say "It's cubes it".  Then when the professor asks "how did you figure that out", smile slyly and say "you didn't *ask* for that".

Comment: @fleablood Thank you, I assumed that I was wrong because I couldn't understand what X does without simplifying the expression.

Comment: Wll, you *could* (with experience and practice) see that the only difference between $\frac 1x + \frac 1{x^2} +\frac 1{x^3}$ and $\frac 1{x^4}+\frac 1{x^5} + \frac 1{x^6}$ is that the powers have been raised to a consistent higher power.  That means the divisor is the same as the dividend but multiplied by $\frac 1{x^3}$ (Hence ak's answer).  So the whole thing is $1 \div \frac 1{x^3} = x^3$. But even if you had the insight to see that, there's no way to say it in "five words or less".  "Five words or less" just means "give my a *final* report".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's se what happens if we simplify the expression.

$(1/x+1/x^2+1/x^3) \div (1/x^4+1/x^5+1/x^6)=$

$\frac {1/x+1/x^2+1/x^3}{1/x^4+1/x^5+1/x^6} =$

$\frac {x^6}{x^6}\frac {1/x+1/x^2+1/x^3}{1/x^4+1/x^5+1/x^6}=$

$ \frac {x^5 + x^4 + x^3}{x^2 + x + 1} =$

$\frac {x^3(x^2 + x + 1)}{x^2 + x+ 1} =$

$\require{cancel}$$\frac {x^3\cancel{(x^2 + x + 1)}}{\cancel{x^2 + x+ 1}}=x^3$.

And that's that

"it cubes $x$" is the appropriate answer.

====

Note though what you *actually* wrote was dead wrong.

$1/x+1/x^2+1/x^3 \div 1/x^4+1/x^5+1/x^6=$

$1/x+1/x^2+\frac {1/x^3}{1/x^4}+1/x^5+1/x^6=$

$1/x+1/x^2+\frac {x^4}{x^3}+1/x^5+1/x^6=$

$1/x+1/x^2+x+1/x^5+1/x^6=$

$\frac {x^5}{x^6} + \frac {x^4}{x^6} + \frac {x^7}{x^6} + \frac x{x^6} + \frac 1{x^6}= $

$\frac {x^5 +x^4 + x^7 + x + 1}{x^6}$

can't be simplified any further.

Comment: Thank you. How did you know to multiply the numerator and denominator by $x^6$? What I did was find the LCD for the numerator and denominator respectively. Your method saves a bit of time.

Comment: My immediate goal was to get rid of the fractions in the denominator to make it simpler. That's all. It would have been more direct and fast to find the LCD is $(\frac 1x + \frac 1x^2 + x^3)$ first but for illustrative purposes I didn't think my thought process would be as clear or immediate than a simplification.  Which made things longs but easier to see and do.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$\frac1{x^4} + \frac1{x^5} + \frac1{x^6} = \frac1{x^3}\left(\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^3}\right)$$

Do you get that now?